# Is there any smart way for me to lock only the needed tables in my database?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres db in which all my tables have a history table. To avoid concurrent writes, I want to lock my table while one editor is editing it. But the issue is from the front end service, the editor any of the table that postgres db is not aware of. I dont want to lock all the tables when the editor is editing it. Is there any smart way for me to lock only the needed tables?

Comment: You need to know what tables are being edited to lock them. Surely when the frontend opens up a form (or whatever) it must know what is being edited at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your use case, but I strongly recommend that you do **not** use table locks for that. That would have unpleasant side effects.

You can hold a table lock only for the duration of a database transaction, so you would have to keep a transaction open for the whole time that the table is edited.

Now the user that edits the table may leave without finishing the editing session, and the transaction and lock stay active indefinitely. That has the following consequences:

- The necessary autovacuum maintenance job can no longer remove dead rows in **any** database table, leading to *bloat*.
- Worse, if the transaction stays open long enough, you may get problems with *transaction ID wraparound*.
- Nobody else can edit the table.

So I recommend some “optimistic locking” approach:

- Do not really lock the table.
- When a user tries to edit a row, make sure that nobody else has changed the row since the user last read it:

  ```
  UPDATE mytable
  SET col1 = ..., ...
  WHERE col1 = <original col1 value>
    AND col2 = <original col2 value>
    ...;
  ```

  If the values are no longer the original values, that `UPDATE` will change 0 rows. Then notify the user that the data were changed concurrently and load the current data again.

If you really want to exclude others from modifying the table, use other synchonization methods than database locks, either something in the application code or PostgreSQL [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS).